# Wrong folder created by Jasmine2 and Protractor

Tags: testing, protractor, automated-tests, jasmine2.0

I've used
Protractor - 4.0.11
Jasmine - 2.5.2
and conf:

```
onPrepare: function() {
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
    new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
      savePath: 'target/reports',
      screenshotsFolder: 'target/screenshots',
      fixedScreenshotName: true,
    })
  );}
```

the HTML report is created and looks like:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BADzo.png)

The link for screenshot in html code of report:

```
<img src="target/screenshots/should-divide-four-and-two.png" width="100" height="100">
```

but the created path is:
"target\reportstarget\screenshots"

I don't know why Jasmine adds the name form savePath "reports" in here.
When code was:

```
onPrepare: function() {
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
    new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
      savePath: 'target/screenshots',
      fixedScreenshotName: true,
    })
  );}
```

folder path was:
report - /target/screenshots
screenshots - /screenshotsscreenshots

Somebody knows how to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `screenshotsFolder` should contain a *relative* to the `savePath` directory path. End your `savePath` with a slash regardless of whether you provide `screenshotsFolder` or not:

```
savePath: 'target/screenshots/'
```